# Previously-deleted rude user back with new account

Tags: discussion, deleted-users, association-bonus

I flagged a rude comment (calling me stupid) from a user I was trying to help - go figure :), and subsequently, that user account appeared to be deleted and my flag marked as "helpful". (**edit**: I'm not sure if the moderator deleted the account, or if the user requested deletion following some ban, or some other chain of events).

The old account is still deleted, but the user is back (judging by the profile photo and the name). And, perhaps due to association bonus (+100 rep), there appears to be no rate-limiting of 1 question-per-week (that I read about in other posts.).

So, my questions are:

1. Why wasn't this new account creation caught by the system, given that it was associated with other StackExchange accounts (if not, due to same name) that caused it to receive an association bonus?
2. What could be done about this pattern? I think it's understandable that I wouldn't want to help this user again.

Comment: Perhaps the user requested deletion themselves? Either way, definitely consider custom-flagging a contribution of that user and explain the situation to a moderator.

Comment: SE just isn't very interested in implementing an authentication system that proves identity.  OpenID only works for people that *want* to use their account.  So spammers and blocked users have free reign, they just create a new account so they can post again.  The only counter-measure in place is for SO users to alert the moderators.  Do so with a custom flag in this case.  But don't expect miracles, proving it is the same user is pretty difficult.  Something as obvious as an identical IP address isn't enough.  The same profile picture, yes.  But deleting the new account just repeats the cycle

Comment: @Pekka 웃: They've done that. I'll let another moderator handle it as I'm not familiar with this particular repeat offender.

Comment: @HansPassant, no, I understand that there is no proof of identity, but I was surprised to find that that user could just link their newly created (pseudonemous) account with their previous Stack Exchange accounts (i.e. on CodeReview, on Meta StackExchange, etc...) and gain an association bonus. That definitely should be easily detectable, no?

Comment: Probably not if the association bonus applied.  If he's a chronic pita on one site then he's usually a pita on another.  So he probably got blocked before on another site and created a new account.  And now uses it on SO as well.

Comment: This is about me, right? You're talking about me, behind my back. I can feel it. I can feel it.

Comment: You'd think it would be easier for them to just not be rude. But I don't think anything short of requiring something like a credit card can prevent people from creating new accounts.

Comment: @Jongware: Prettttty sure we're talking about Won't. :P

Comment: Uh. Oh. So everybody visiting my profile only does so to backup my picture for later flagging as a come-back-offender? Goodness gracious. Gotta go back to that fancy mosaic SO provided me with at the start...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're right, this looks like a bug related to the account-association process. The previous account was deleted by a moderator as a sock puppet of a currently suspended user. It was deleted in such a way that the system should have been blocking creation of any new accounts from that location for a while. This is part of the anti-trolling / anti-spam system on the site, which we sometimes also use for people evading suspensions or question bans.

Perhaps the fact that they were recreating an account via association with other established accounts on other sites (that should have been removed as well) allowed them to bypass this block. I'll pass this along to a developer to look at, since we do occasionally run into edge cases where people are able to work around blocks.

Association bonuses being used by recreated accounts is [a known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/association-bonus-not-removed-upon-account-deletion) and is sometimes exploited by sock puppet operators. That should not be allowed to be re-applied to accounts on a site where a previous account had been deleted.

All you can do in this case is flag the new account for us to look into. It also helps us out if you can make some kind of reference to the old account so we can check why it was deleted. I've once again removed this account and marked them as no longer being welcome to participate here.

Comment: Does the association bonus still get applied to new accounts if the votes were later reversed by the anti-cheating script?

Comment: @Pokechu22 - Yes, I believe so. I think once your account has earned the association bonus, it's permanently associated with your account across sites.

Comment: Association bonuses need a complete rethink, giving me 100 rep on any site visit (I tend to vote) rather then just having a network wide flag to show I am a experienced user on at least on site, does not seem right.

Comment: Update: the user is back (the second time) with a new SO account linked with other StackExchange accounts and ... 100+ rep due to association bonus.