# Serial voting reversal doesn't remove association bonus

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, association-bonus

First off, I'm aware that this has been discussed before on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting) and on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215516/shouldnt-the-association-bonus-acquired-via-serial-upvoting-be-reversed), although I believe there is a new dimension to this now that wasn't previously discussed.

Lately I've been seeing a lot more of these kinds of situation:

1. New user gets serially upvoted to [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/234215)
2. Serial voting targeting new user gets reversed - by flag or script
3. New user keeps association bonus regardless

I would assume that the rationale many new users choose to opt for serial voting or serially vote on someone are among:

- Giving them the ability to comment
- Giving them the ability to upvote

Now, both of that is possible with just the association bonus, and even completly across the network. I've noticed a conspicous number of cases where users have been serially upvoted to the point of the association bonus, but no further.

This could also easily be used to set up network-wide vote privileged sockpuppet accounts to conceal the fact that the real serial voting is going on on other SE sites.

All in all I think this type of abuse warrants a lot more attention from SE then it currently gets (which is none - usually, at best the votes themselves get reversed, the association bonus usually stays).

In the two linked threads about this issue, no further action has been taken and no response from SE has been provided.

So my question is:

Does the keeping of the association bonus fail to deter new users from serial voting? Should the association bonus be reworked or at least revoked with the offending votes? Is this even possible under its current implementation?

Here are some examples of what I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I believe this sort of abuse of the voting system is specifically targeted not to just get rep, but to get and keep the association bonus, even if those accounts do not keep the rep. After all, the association bonus is all you need for sockpuppet activity and to bypass the comment barrier intended to stop people misusing the site from using comments to ask extra questions and be a general nuisance.

Comment: In my opinion, there should be some kind of systems that checks for serial voting of such kind. If so, human mods should review those voting activity, and the reputation and votes should be removed accordingly.

Comment: But if reversal is already happening correctly for serial voting, corresponding reputation can easily be retracted as well. And if the new number is less than the threshold for offering association bonus, that can be retracted as a result.

Comment: @CinCout I'm not doubting it's technically possible, but it's not happening now so that suggests either it's not high priority or some technical quirk of the system prevents it from being quickly implemented.

Comment: @SteveFest Magisch is unearthing fraud faster, and in such large quantities, than it cannot be reviewed/actioned by the SO staff available, even if they wanted to, (whch, in itself, is an issue - SO does not want to lose thousands of accounts in a short period, even if they were fraudulently obtained/used).

Comment: @MartinJames I agree with the point that we shouldn't lose thousands of accounts/ or active users that got serial upvoted. My suggested system may not work as how I intended as your comment pointed. But the thing is, that such users have an advantage to those users who gained the reputation on their own, and that is what we don't want SO to happen. Shouldn't there be some sort of reversal/punishments for such actions? But not just let those users get away.

Comment: @MartinJames: that's just conjecture with no basis in truth. We have had no issues handling the flags Magisch has been casting. If there have been delays in getting series reverted, then that's only due to the long US holiday weekend. I've personally removed more fraudulent accounts in a single day than Magisch has raised flags in a day, by a long mile.

Comment: let's not forget that even if deleted, a re-created account still keeps the bonus: [Association Bonus not removed upon account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/association-bonus-not-removed-upon-account-deletion), so unless someone goes in and manually clears the flag in the database, even a deleted account is still going to benefit from the bonus if someone tries to create the account again

Comment: @MartinJames - While we certainly appreciate the help that Magisch has been providing, the vast majority of voting fraud cases we deal with are detected and handled without the community ever knowing. Because this is a more public effort involving multiple Meta posts, you're hearing about it more frequently. Deleting clear and obvious sock puppets is one of the fastest things I can do, but many of these cases are more complex than that and there have been a number of false positives. SE employees have been pointing out the puppets and actually encouraging us to delete them when found.

Comment: Association bonuses have been a source of abuse, such as with [deleted accounts that keep getting recreated with the bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306241/previously-deleted-rude-user-back-with-new-account). The [automatic suspension of recreated accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278803/135615) helped with that, but people still do use this from time to time to boost puppets. I'll let an SE employee comment on it, but I know they recognize the issues here and it sounds like removing the network-wide bonus has some challenges similar to revoking badges.

Comment: @BradLarson I hope y'all are not angry at me by proxy. I didn't make these comments and I've always appreciated that my efforts are but a very small part of how cheaters are dealt with on SO

Comment: @Magisch - Absolutely not, we really appreciate the help. Your queries have pointed out many cases that our tools missed, and they've also uncovered some more subtle issues. The new moderators helped clean out the flag queue, so now is a pretty good time to work through these. I just wanted to counter the idea that SE is actively working against stopping voting fraud because they don't want to lose users. That's not been my experience at all.

Comment: 'SE employees have been pointing out the puppets and actually encouraging us to delete them when found', 'That's not been my experience at all' - good to hear, overall;)

Comment: Rep or badges wrongfully obtained arent worth a dime. Neither are the others, but at least we can proud of the rep & badges _real_ users granted us by voting for our posts. Burn the serial voting. Keep up the excellent work Magisch & our mods.