# Why am I still a trusted user?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

At 179 reputation, I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291958/1977587) question and got two upvotes taking my reputation to 199. My answer was soon accepted and I had 214 reputation. On crossing the 200 rep mark, I was awarded a further 100 bonus reputation because I became a trusted user.

A day later there was a better answer to the question and that answer was accepted stripping me of my 15 accepted answer reputation.

I understand that, but should I still be having the trusted user 100 reputation bonus because without the accepted answer I would not have crossed the 200 rep mark anyway?

I now have 299 reputation = 199 (reputation I earned) + 100 (reputation because I crossed the 200 rep mark).

P.S. A similar situation would apply to my just earned 'yearling' badge as well.

Comment: I see your reputation as 299, not the 199 you think you have.

Comment: That is correct, but 299 = 199 + 100 (this is solely because I crossed 200 at some point)

Comment: I should perhaps add that to the question.

Comment: The site founders did not consider using rep as a measure of technical prowess, they used it as a measure of how well you know the web site.  Gradually giving you access to more powerful tools as you gain more experience.  You did not get to know it less well.

Comment: @HansPassant That said, you can lose rep (such as the 15 OP lost when the accepted answer changed) and lose access to some of those tools as a result. And, in the case of site graduation, you can even lose privileges while still gaining rep. Which honestly seems kind of weird. For example, on Aviation, I still don't have enough rep to unprotect a question that I myself protected a year or two ago.

Comment: The 100 reputation bonus might exist to provide a privilege buffer. It would be unfair to become a trusted user and then immediatly losing trust after (f.e.) someone with a better answer comes along. With the buffer you have to do quite some damage to loose trust once you earned it. In other words, I believe we can still trust you even if someone was able to provide a better answer.

Comment: A [quick search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=association+bonus) may get you some similar results.

Comment: Pedantic comment: [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege is awarded at 20K rep. "We trust you on other network sites" is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This seems like a legitimate scenario to me, you did earn the 200 rep mark for the 100 rep association bonus, which led to you legitimately keeping it as it was properly earned, even if the 15 reputation from the accept mark was subsequently lost at a later time.

Unless there was voting fraud involved, there should be no issue here, nor any revoking of the bonus in the future.

Comment: even if voting fraud is involved [nothing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356142/serial-voting-reversal-doesnt-remove-association-bonus) will [happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting)

Comment: @rene shhhhh, no one is supposed to know about that. Voting fraud *always* gets caught and reversed, every single time. 100%. Always.

Answer (score 9):

The system does a one-time application of the association bonus, adding 100 reputation to your account.  From there, the normal rules of reputation apply.

Since the association bonus is not associated with [any kind of privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), it is not revoked or reversed when your reputation dips below a certain point.

Additionally, a bit of situational math would indicate that you earned the association bonus *before* you <s>were voted down</s> had your answer unaccepted, so it would have applied regardless.

Comment: To add to this, if you are at 199 on *another* site as well, when that site gets the association bonus, it hits 200 and grants the *first* site an association bonus as well. If we stripped people of that when they dropped down below the threshold, this edge case would be really hard to catch. That is, they jumped up to 200, then lost the thing that made them go over 200, but had a cyclic association bonus in between.

Answer (score 5):

As association bonus, 100 points are awarded to the user who reaches 200 (magic number) reputation on any site across Stack Exchange network. This happens only once across all network sites. This bonus (100 points) is added to all the network sites user is active on. Further, if user connects to any network site in future where he was not active when the association bonus was awarded, 100 points are still awarded on that network site.

When user earn 200 reputation, Stack Exchange considers the user as trusted user. This is because, by this time:

- User has learned rules of site
- User has involved in activities on site
- User has maintained overall positive record
- User does not look one time visitor

Even though reputation goes down below 200 for some reason, above facts (what user has learned) does not change. So, user still remains trusted user even if reputation goes below 200.

Considering the motive of "trusted user" concept, reputation earned as a result of voting fraud should not be counted. But it seems being counted looking at other answers. That means, if a part or full of your reputation earned is result of voting fraud and you reach threshold of 200, association bonus of 100 will be awarded to you. But if the fraud is caught and the reputation goes below 200 (subtracting 100 from bonus) as reputation reversal, user still own the additional 100 association bonus and also remains trusted user. I am not sure this is as a result of bug or design.